# Is Starshift Crisis still published?

Tags: webcomics, starslip-crisis

The webcomic [Starslip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starslip#Starslip) (by Kristofer Straub) was originally *Starshift Crisis*. It [changed its name](http://starslip.com/2011/04/25/starshift-crisis/) due to potential legal issues with the original name. This wasn't a simple name change, though: the change was worked into the storyline; Straub translated the meta-level reboot into an in-story universe shift. For a brief time, the [old site](http://www.starshiftcrisis.com/) and the [new site](http://starslip.com/) ran parallel storylines in the two universes, until…

> From memory: the starshift drive and the starslip drive are both methods of FTL travel. In *Starshift*, it was discovered that the starshift not only moved the ship but potentially changed the universe — and this happened when the *Fuseli* jumped from a universe where the starshift drive is used to a universe where the starslip drive is used, abruptly ending the *Starshift* storyline.

Only the starslip version is visible now. It would be interesting to read the two versions in parallel. Is there any way to read *Starshift Crisis* now?

Comment: I've never heard of it before, but if legal issues precipitated the name change then there would be a good reason you can't find the old one!

Comment: @jprete The potential legal issues turned out [not to matter anyway](http://starslip.com/2011/04/25/starshift-crisis/).

Answer (score 1):

The discussion on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kris_Straub) would suggests that there were only *marginal* differences between the parallel strips, notably the lettering (e.g. in one strip it's referred to as "*Starslip*" and in the other it's referred to as "*Starshift*").

There was evidently a crossover strip which I've been able to find on Archive.org (see middle panel below). After this was shown, both sets were then made identical.

A few weeks later, the earlier and legally contentious strip was removed from the internet completely and all dynamic links were diverted to the [new site](http://starslip.chainsawsuit.com/starslip/starslip-number-65/).

[image: Starslip Crisis I]

[image: Starshift Crisis]

[image: Starslip Crisis II]